# inject custom service in jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I have written a yathzee game for school, now I need to unit test my calculations. 
I try to inject my service, but it's undefined. Tried lots of things, really no clue how to set it up. I was happy karma started working.
So this is my test file

```
describe('Users factory', function() {
beforeEach(module('yathzeeCalculateService'));

var myservice;

beforeEach(inject('yathzeeCalculateService', function(yathzeeCalculateService){
  myservice = yathzeeCalculateService;
}));


describe('Test chance', function() {
  it('should be defined', function(){
    expect(myservice).toBeTruthy();
  });
    it('good count', function(){
        var dices = [1,1,1,1,1];
        expect(myservice.sum(dices)).toEqual(5);
    });
});
});
```

This is my service

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').factory('yathzeeCalculateService', yathzeeCalculateService);
yathzeeCalculateService.$inject = ['_'];

function yathzeeCalculateService(_) {

   ... 
    return {

        sum : sum,
        getStraight : getStraight,
        isSmallStraight : isSmallStraight,
        isLargeStraight : isLargeStraight,
        getSameCount : getSameCount,
        manyOfAKind : manyOfAKind,
        getAmountOfArrayNumber : getAmountOfArrayNumber,
        threeOfAKind : threeOfAKind,
        fourOfAKind : fourOfAKind,
        yahtzee : yahtzee,
        fullHouse : fullHouse
    };
}
})();
```

I use underscore for array functions, does it have to be injected in the test? And if, how?

Answer (score 0):

The name of module is wrong the module name should be proper

invalid module name

```
beforeEach(module('yathzeeCalculateService'));
```

you have to use

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```

Comment: Did that, but now I got "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string". When I got that error in the past, there was a ']' misplaced and my code didn't worked, but now my app runs fine, but those tests ...